# Не работает nl2br

Tags: php

Написал кусочек кода для компиляции с++ кода, сам код:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
$url = "http://cpp.sh/run";//url для отправки post запроса
$code = $_POST['code'];//получение кода программы из textbox
$input = $_POST['stdin'];
$data = array(//данные которые будут отправлятся 
'dlct' => 'cpp14', 
'wrng' => 'Wall', 
'inpt' => 'text',
'stdin' => $input,//вводимые данные
'source' => $code);
$context_options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
$context  = stream_context_create($context_options);//отправляем
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);//получаем ответ
preg_match('/"output":"(.*)","exitmsg"/', $result, $vivod);//Находим вывод
$vivod = $vivod[1];
}
?>

<form action="c++.php" role="form" method="post">   
<p>Вводимые данные:</p><textarea rows="10" cols="60" type="text" name="stdin"><?php if(!empty($_POST['stdin'])) echo $_POST['stdin'];?></textarea><br>
<p>Код программы:</p><textarea rows="15" cols="60" type="text" name="code">        <?php if(!empty($_POST['code'])) echo $_POST['code'];?></textarea><br>
<br><button type="submit">Получить</button> 
</form>       
<?php 
if(!empty($vivod)){
echo nl2br("<p>Выходные данные:</p><textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"60\">".$vivod."</textarea>");             
}         
?>
<br>
```

Только выводит такой код:
`Введите a -> Введите b -> Введите c -> Полное ветвление\nMax=3\n__________________________________________\nНеполное ветвление\n__________________________________________\nMax=3\n__________________________________________\nСпособ 3-ий\nMax=3\n__________________________________________\nСпособ 4-ый\nMax=3\n`
Как видно \n не обрабатывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в nl2br, а в данных которые вы ей передаете. Функция nl2br заменяет переносы строк на `<br>`, а вы передаете ей одну строку с символами `\n`.

Есть два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Исправить вывод вашей С++ команды, добавив реальные переносы строк
2. Заменить nl2br на str_replace

   ```
   str_replace('\n','<br>',$vivod);
   ```

Comment: Второй вариант отлично решил проблему, большое спасибо!